# What are sources of information for monitoring other than logging

Tags: logging, monitoring, health-monitoring

As in title I would like to ask what sources of information other than logging can be used for monitoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a health-side to your application (assuming you mean a web-application) that is constantly updated (or only checks by loading the side) by a background job that verifies that e.g. your database is still online an reachable.